# Flattening nested java lists in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

I am working in Scala with java libraries. One of these libraries returns a list of lists. I want to flatten the list.

Example:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
var parentList : util.List[util.List[Int]] = null
parentList = new util.ArrayList[util.List[Int]]

parentList.asScala.flatten // error
```

I have used *asScala* converter but I'm still meeting an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `.asScala` on every inner list :

```
scala> parentList.asScala.map(_.asScala)
res0: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Int]] = ArrayBuffer()

scala> parentList.asScala.map(_.asScala).flatten
res1: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer()
```

Note that calling `.map` and then `.flatten` can be done in one step using `.flatMap` :

```
scala> parentList.asScala.flatMap(_.asScala)
res2: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer()
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to convert the inner `List[Int]`:

```
parentList.asScala.flatMap(_.asScala)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
parentList.asScala.flatMap.map(_.toSeq)
```

This will do the trick.